# Disable SCSI (CAM) device

Tags: freebsd, scsi, freenas

I want to tell the FreeBSD kernel to completely ignore a SCSI [`cam(4)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cam&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%208.0-RELEASE) device.

```
# cat /var/run/dmesg.boot | grep '\<da1\>'
ada0: 600.000MB/s transfers (SATA 3.x, da1 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus4 target 0 lun 1
da1: <HP iLO LUN 01 Media 0 2.09> Fixed Direct Access SCSI-0 device 
da1: Serial Number 000002660A01
da1: 40.000MB/s transfers
da1: 1024MB (2097152 512 byte sectors: 64H 32S/T 1024C)
da1: quirks=0x2<NO_6_BYTE>

# camcontrol devlist
<ST1000DM003-1ER162 CC46>          at scbus1 target 0 lun 0 (pass0,ada0)
<ST1000DM003-1ER162 CC46>          at scbus2 target 0 lun 0 (pass1,ada1)
<HP iLO Internal SD-CARD 2.09>     at scbus4 target 0 lun 0 (pass2,da0)
<HP iLO LUN 01 Media 0 2.09>       at scbus4 target 0 lun 1 (pass3,da1)
```

I don't know what the `da1` device is, nor do I want it visible on my system. FreeNAS sees this device and offers it as an option to create a volume on, which is not something I ever want to do.

How can I accomplish this?

*Update*: It appears this can be accomplished using [device hints](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/device-hints.html), setting the keyword "disabled"=1:

```
hint.driver.unit.keyword="value"
```

The only problem is, I'm not sure how to specify `driver` and `unit` for this device.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have given this looks like an SD card reader that is part of the [HP iLO](http://www8.hp.com/uk/en/products/servers/ilo/) (some sort of administrator interface ?).

To disable it with device hints you have all the information there.

The device driver is `da` and the unit is `1`, which is easy to see under FreeBSD.

```
hint.da.1.disable="1"
```

Should do what you want.